# Changing settings panel in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like to remove "Open properties on select" from the settings panel of the Forge viewer. I manage to get the settingsPanel of the viewer, but all the remove functions return false. Is this possible to do at all and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain handles to the setting items by accessing its control children so try:

```
viewer.getSettingsPanel().controls['ViewerSettingsPanel0-0-adsk_settings_control_id_8'].setVisibility(false)
```

For a more assured approach you may iterate the controls and inspect their `checkElement` or `savekey` to find the one you are after.